# How to zoom on text on hover using scss and html

Tags: html, css, sass, hover, css-transitions

I'm newer to HTML, and I am curious about hover effects currently. I want text on hover to scale up 1.5 in 0.2s. It didn't do anything. It could be an issue with the SCSS.

Here is the code:

```css
section.hero .wrd-content:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="wrd-content">
    <h2>Hello... I am</h2>
    <h1>FirstName <br>LastName </h1>
    <hr>
    </hr>
  </div>
</section>
```

I'm just a little lost on where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked for me.
Did you make sure to include the CSS properly in the HTML file?
So with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="PathToYourCSS.css">
```

You would then have to insert this in the header area of the HTML file.
I hope I was able to help you and wish you lots of success and fun.

Comment: Not sure what the issue was, but I have it working now.